# Extract value label in command [stata]

Tags: label, stata, decode

I am trying to create a new `string` variable that combines the `string` of a `real` number (an ID) with a name. The name is a `numeric` variable with a `value label`.

Example data can be found below:

```
* Input Data
clear
input long num id
1 689347
2 972623
end
label values num num
label def num 1 "Label A" 2 "Label B"

 +------------------+
 |     num       id |
 |------------------|
 | Label A   689347 |
 | Label B   972623 |
 +------------------+
```

What I would like to do is create a `string` of the type `689347 - Label A`. This is very easy to do by simply using `decode` on `num`, then writing a new `string` as follows:

```
tempvar numstr
decode num, gen(`numstr')
gen label = string(id) + " - " + `numstr'

 +-------------------------------------+
 |     num       id              label |
 |-------------------------------------|
 | Label A   689347   689347 - Label A |
 | Label B   972623   972623 - Label B |
 +-------------------------------------+
```

This is already pretty easy, but is there a way to do this in one line, without the `decode` command?

For example something like:

```
gen label = string(if) + " " + string(num)
```

The problem with this is, of course, that this will just give a `string` of the `real` number value (1 and 2) that `num` takes on.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767838/use-value-label-in-if-command-in-stata) you can see how to reference the `value label` in an `if` command.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to tell Stata to create a string and pull the `value label` instead of the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can do is two lines.

```
decode num, generate(label)
replace label = string(id) + " - " + label
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the solution I already have in the question, but without the tempvar (meaning I would need to add a third line to drop the _label_ variable anyway.

Comment: @AaronWolf this is not exactly the same. This is two lines instead of three. Why would you drop `label`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what you did there. Yeah, that's probably the best we can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `decode`, then this does the trick:

```
generate label = ""

forvalues i = 1 / 2 {
    replace label = string(id) + " - " + "`: label num `i''" in `i'
}
```

Comment: Note the implication, You need to loop over observations as the value label concerned will differ from observation to observation (unless exceptionally all values have the same value label).

Comment: This is also more intensive than the solution I proposed. The point isn't that I am allergic to `decode`. The point is simply whether there is a way to do this on one line instead of three.

Comment: In your post you ask: "...is there a way to do this in one line, without the decode command?...". There isn't one that can do it in one line but there is one (above) that can do it without `decode`.

Comment: By the way, I did not see any concerns regarding intensity voiced in your question.